# JavaCV Error in Android Application

Tags: java, android, javacv

i am developing an Android app, which grabbs every picture from a video and converts it to a Bitmap to analyze them in the next step.
But the App Crashes, if FFmpegFrameGrabber g1 = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(f2); is called.
The file definitely exists. I am using JavaCV 1.2 and Android 2.3.3 in Android Studio.

```
private void VideoAuswerten() throws FrameGrabber.Exception {
    File f2 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/myApp/example.mp4");
    if (f2.exists() != true) {
        return; 
    }
    FFmpegFrameGrabber g1 = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(f2);

    if (g1 == null)
    {
        textView4.setText("Error");
        return;
    }
    try {
        g1.start();

        for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++) {

            AndroidFrameConverter afc = new AndroidFrameConverter();

            Bitmap bitm = afc.convert(g1.grab());
        }
  }
  catch (FrameGrabber.Exception e) {

  }
}
```

i am getting following errors:

```
this = {ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller@830007790464} "com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller"
ex = {InvocationTargetException@830008194192} "java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException"
cause = {VerifyError@830008201736} "java.lang.VerifyError: org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameGrabber"
```

Can you tell me, whats could be the problem? I´m just a beginner in programming Android Apps in Java and habe absolutely no idea what could be wrong.
Thank you!